# How to use Roslyn to inpect code for both c# and vb.net

Tags: roslyn

Is there a more abstract way to parse .Net code?

Seems all the classes are specific to the .Net language, you would think there would be a abstract class for say Class, Member, similar as what is done reflection.

I'm looking for a way to inspect the parsed code but using shared classes for both c# or vb.net.

Also most of the links seem to be outdated, so if anyone has some new links I would appreciate it.

Any links or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: The `SemanticModel` and `ISymbol` API's are language neutral, and provide more information than reflection does. If you need details about method bodies, the `IOperation` API's may be what you are looking for.

Comment: Can't seem to get much information from just the SemanticModel. For examples all the Types, Members.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Build an analyzer to run in Visual Studio or a standalone (command line) tool? Do you have a `Compilation`? Start with `compilation.Assembly.GlobalNamespace.GetMembers()` and call `GetMembers`recursively on those members that are `INamespaceSymbol`.

Comment: Trying to inspect code with-out using specific c# or vb.net classes.

Comment: Define "inspect code". See my previous comment.

Comment: Kris maybe you could provide a sample? also using CSharpCompilation but that's specific to c# trying to  minimize language specific api